# Including non-hypothesized interaction terms in moderation analysis

Tags: regression, interaction

I am running a moderation analysis using hierarchical linear regression. I have two predictor variables and two moderating variables and I am interested in their interactions to predict an outcome. My analysis includes the four possible interaction terms, but I am only theoretically interested in two - is it ok to leave the other two interaction terms in analysis or should I only include the interaction terms that I specifically predicted?

Comment: I can't think of a reason it wouldn't be okay...can you? It's fine to sincerely hypothesize the typical null (i.e., no interaction) if you're interested in controlling for it at whatever value it actually takes in your sample. You can't interpret this like a confirmatory analysis of a prior hypothesis, but most people don't interpret these differently than analyses for exploratory or statistical control purposes anyway...

Comment: I have to side with @NickStauner here, I think that your situation calls for including only the two interaction terms that you've hypothesized unless you also want to explore the other two.

Comment: Oh, that's not what I meant. Hypothesizing the null is quite different from assuming and not testing it. But it sounds like you see a reason not to include the two interaction terms for which there are no hypotheses?

Comment: Oh, apologies, I didn't understand your comment fully. No, I don't see a reason to include a term (be it an interaction term or otherwise) if you haven't hypothesized it, unless you want to see how it comes out. This is not unlike the typical procedure when doing an ANCOVA--you would rarely include the interaction between the continuous covariate and the categorical factor(s) by default, unless you had hypothesized such an interaction. Also, in hierarchical (and single-level) regression, having interaction terms muddies the interpretation of any term included in the interaction.